# A Problem about finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group with $\vert G\vert=60$ and $\vert Z(G)\vert$ is divisible by 4. I wanted to show that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order 5.

I intend to solve it by using sylow's theorem as follows:

Since $\vert G\vert=60=2^2.3.5,$ then $G$ has Sylow 5-subgroups of order 5, and $n_5\in \{1,6\}$. I need help on how to proceed, please.

Comment: Just to clarify, you haven't used any of the Sylow's theorems here, only the definition of a Sylow subgroup (except that groups of order $2$ are not Sylow!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

We have that

$$|Z(G)|\in\{4,\,12,\,20,\,60\}\;\implies\;|G/Z(G)|\in\{15,\,5,\,3,\,1\}\implies G/Z(G)\;$$

is cyclic. But *no group whatsoever* divided by its center can be cyclic **non-trivial**, so it must be $G/Z(G)=1\iff G\;$ is abelian.

Comment: Is it correct to say that: the Sylow 5-subgroups of $G$ are abelian and hence $G$ is not simple. Therefore, the unique Sylow-5-group of order 5 is normal?

Comment: @AyshaA. What has to do the fact that some subgroups are abelian or not with the group being simple or not? For example, $\;A_5\;$ is simple and has lots of abelian subgroups...

Comment: Okay, how do I conclude that the Sylow 5-subgroup is normal in $G$?

Comment: @AyshaA. If you understood my answer, it is proved $\;G\;$ is actually abelian, so then **all its subgroups** are trivially normal...

Answer (score 1):

By Sylow III, the number of Sylow-$5$-subgroups $s_5$ divides $2^2\cdot 3$ and is congruent $1$ modulo $5$. Hence it is $1$ or $6$. But every group of order $60$ having more than one Sylow-$5$-subgroup is simple (see Conrad, Consequences of the Sylow Theorems, Theorem $8.3$). This is a contradiction to $|Z(G)|\ge 4$. It follows that $s_5=1$, so that the unique Sylow-$5$-group of order $5$ is normal.